# Blender 2.8 glTF Export Error

Tags: gltf

Still getting my feet wet with the glTF exporter in Blender 2.8 (May 8th build). I could use some help better understanding this error below.

`````
  File "/Applications/Blender 2.8/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/__init__.py", line 426, in execute
    return gltf2_blender_export.save(context, export_settings)
  File "/Applications/Blender 2.8/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_export.py", line 40, in save
    json, buffer = __export(export_settings)
  File "/Applications/Blender 2.8/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_export.py", line 54, in __export
    __gather_gltf(exporter, export_settings)
  File "/Applications/Blender 2.8/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_export.py", line 69, in __gather_gltf
    scenes, animations = gltf2_blender_gather.gather_gltf2(export_settings)
  File "/Applications/Blender 2.8/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather.py", line 34, in gather_gltf2
    scenes.append(__gather_scene(blender_scene, export_settings))
  File "/Applications/Blender 2.8/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 51, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Applications/Blender 2.8/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather.py", line 52, in __gather_scene
    node = gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.gather_node(blender_object, export_settings)
  File "/Applications/Blender 2.8/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 51, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Applications/Blender 2.8/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 44, in gather_node
    mesh=__gather_mesh(blender_object, export_settings),
  File "/Applications/Blender 2.8/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather_nodes.py", line 246, in __gather_mesh
    result = gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.gather_mesh(blender_mesh, vertex_groups, modifiers, skip_filter, export_settings)
  File "/Applications/Blender 2.8/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 51, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Applications/Blender 2.8/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.py", line 38, in gather_mesh
    primitives=__gather_primitives(blender_mesh, vertex_groups, modifiers, export_settings),
  File "/Applications/Blender 2.8/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather_mesh.py", line 89, in __gather_primitives
    return gltf2_blender_gather_primitives.gather_primitives(blender_mesh, vertex_groups, modifiers, export_settings)
  File "/Applications/Blender 2.8/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather_cache.py", line 51, in wrapper_cached
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Applications/Blender 2.8/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_gather_primitives.py", line 47, in gather_primitives
    None, blender_mesh, vertex_groups, modifiers, export_settings)
  File "/Applications/Blender 2.8/blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/gltf2_blender_extract.py", line 618, in extract_primitives
    uv = blender_mesh.uv_layers[tex_coord_index].data[loop_index].uv
IndexError: bpy_prop_collection[index]: index 2 out of range, size 0

location: <unknown location>:-1 ````
`````

Comment: Start by trying a newer build, see if it still happens.  If it still happens, can you share a test model that causes this message to be produced?